# python for remote database connection

Tags: python-2.7

I have code in raspberry pi which should send sensor data to remote mysql server of windows 7.I have modified my.cnf file in raspberry pi for bind- address, also I have done setting as follows,

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED by 'mumbai';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

and I have the code as below,

```
import MySQLdb
def temp_sensor():
   conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '192.168.1.103', user = 'root', passwd
       = 'mumbai', db = 'weather', port = 3306)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
  while True:
        try:
             date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
             temp,humidity,light = main.reading()
             args= ('192.168.1.145', 'b8:27:eb:06:e4:4b', 'Temp_PI', temp)
             cursor.callproc('SPR_IU_Sensor_Data',args)
             conn.commit()
             time.sleep(interval2)
        except MySQLdb.Error,  e:
             print 'Error %d: %s' % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

which gives error as,

```
 Process Process-1:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258,
    self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "procedure2.py", line 19, in temp_sensor
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '192.168.1.103', user = 'root',
    passwd = 'mumbai', db = 'weather', port = 3306)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line
     81, in Connect
     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line
     187, in __init__
      super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
      OperationalError: (1130, "Host '192.168.1.145' is not allowed to
       connect to this MySQL server")
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is a need to grant privileges in mysql server of windows 7